# Open MS-Access encrypted database in Runtime version with UserControl false

Tags: ms-access, encryption

I work with Access runtime version and I need to open an encrypted database `.accdb`. I created a dummy file to work with `getobject` and `opencurrentdatabase` statement. I can't  work with `CreateObject("Access.Application")` or `new access.application` because this is the runtime version.

My code is this, and works fine but when I open the encrypted database the `UserControl` property is false, and it opens whith any access message like `docm.setwarnings` in false and "docm.setwarnings true" doesn't work.

```
Option Compare Database

Dim appRT As Object

Public Sub OpenEncryptDb()
Const Q As String = """"

strPathEncryptDb = CurrentProject.Path & "\encryptdb.accdb"
strPathToDummy2 = CurrentProject.Path & "\dummy.accdb"
strPathToRuntime = SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "msaccess.exe"

Shell Q & strPathToRuntime & Q & " /RUNTIME " & Q & strPathToDummy2 & Q, vbNormalFocus

Set appRT = GetObject(strPathToDummy2)
With appRT
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strPathEncryptDb, False, "123456" 'open encrypt database
    .DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
End With
End Sub
```

I shared the code in this link
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsgXxStf7QGagQZIk8hcJShbCIye

open  first the master.accdb file. Note that when you open the final file "encryptdb.accdb", you can delete rows and you don't receive any  confirmation message that regularly you receive when you delete rows in MS-Access like "master.accdb"